# Sharing memory between Python shells run by Electron

Tags: python, concurrency, electron, shared-memory

I'm currently working on a desktop application that makes use of React for frontend and runs through an electron window. Electron needs to be able to communicate with my Python backend. I've found an example online that works fine for running a simple Python script from Electron and returning the result to React.

Electron code that waits for signal from React:

```
ipcMain.on("REACT_TEST_PYTHON", (event, args) => {
  let pyshell = new PythonShell(
    path.join(__dirname, "../background/python/test.py"),
    {
      args: [args.test],
    }
  );
  pyshell.on("message", function (results) {
    mainWindow.webContents.send("ELECTRON_TESTED_PYTHON", { tasks: results });
  });
})
```

test.py that is being run by electron:

```
import sys

data = sys.argv[1]

def factorial(x):
    if x == 1 :
        return 1
    else:
        return x * factorial(x-1)

print(factorial( int(data) ))
```

I completely understand how this works, but for my application the python scripts will not be as simple. Basically, I want electron to create a Python shell that starts a named task. This Python shell should continue running in the background while the frontend works normally. The part I'm stuck on is figuring out how to access data from this initial python shell from a different python shell created by a subsequent signal in electron. If that doesn't make sense this is my intended pipeline:

1. User clicks React button to start "Task1"
2. Electron gets signal from React and starts a Python shell to start "Task1". This python shell is running in the background (Electron should not wait for a result to continue processing).
3. Later on, user decides to click React button to cancel "Task1"
4. Electron gets signal from React and creates a new Python shell to cancel "Task1". In order to do this the new Python shell needs to access data from the original Python shell.
5. This new Python shell should also close the original Python shell so that it doesn't continue to try and run "Task1"

**What would be the best way to do this?**

Some thoughts I've had on how to do this:

- Creating a file where necessary data for "Task1" could be written. I think I would need the `mmap` module in order to use some kind of shared memory between the shells (but I could be wrong). Would also need to figure out how to close the original Python shell.
- Somehow saving a reference to the original Python shell which could allow for Electron to cancel "Task1" using the original shell. Not sure if this is possible though since the original Python shell will still be running, I doubt I could access the shell while its in the middle of processing.

Thank you for any help or insight you can provide! I apologize that this may be a confusing question, please let me know if I can clear anything up.

Comment: I'm no expert in Python that's for sure, but could you get the PID of `script1.py`. IE: [`os.getPid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid) and return it to Electron. With that, you would then be able to kill the process (if needed) by passing it as an argument to `script2.py`. IE: [`os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill).

Comment: Alternatively, how about using Node's [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) command such as [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options). Reference could be maintained as a variable and just [`subprocess.kill`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal) when needed. I haven’t used these commands yet so I’m not 100% on suitability or use.

Comment: Thanks that will definitely work for killing the original shell, now I just need to figure out the best method of sharing data between shells..

Comment: I think Node's [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) is the way to go. Managing your Python scripts creations and terminations from Electron gives you full control in that layer. IE: Not splitting control between Electron to start scripts and Python to terminate scripts. Continue looking at the [`python-shell`](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) library. See [Exchanging data between Node and Python](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell#exchanging-data-between-node-and-python) for more information. Any issues let me know.

Comment: somehow didn't find that documentation before! I should be able to figure that out now, thanks again!